# How to move smoothly header image from left to right in html5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a header image and I want to move from left to right smoothly using jQuery.

I searched Google and stackoverflow, but didn't get what I needed.

HTML5 code:

```
<header>
  <div class="move">
    <img src="http://s10.postimg.org/noxw294zd/banner.png" alt="banner" />
  </div>
</header>
```

I used `<marquee>` for simple method, but I need it to moving smoothly.

How do I create the effect I'm looking for?

Comment: @AndrewBarber http://i.imgur.com/V5P1jHM.jpg

Comment: @jdphenix great. Now I can't look at my browser without freezing in terror! Thanks! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using CSS keyFrames

put an ID animate-area on your div that you want to keep moving and add CSS like this:

```
@keyframes animatedBackground {
  from { background-position: 0 0; }
  to { background-position: 100% 0; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes animatedBackground {
  from { background-position: 0 0; }
  to { background-position: 100% 0; }
}
@-ms-keyframes animatedBackground {
  from { background-position: 0 0; }
  to { background-position: 100% 0; }
}
@-moz-keyframes animatedBackground {
  from { background-position: 0 0; }
  to { background-position: 100% 0; }
}

#animate-area { 
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(your url here);
  background-position: 0px 0px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;

  animation: animatedBackground 140s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation: animatedBackground 140s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: animatedBackground 140s linear infinite;


  -webkit-animation: animatedBackground 140s linear infinite;
}
```

This will move your image from right to left in a loop

WORKING Example : http://plnkr.co/edit/MLSlItGZhMIY4szOcPeR?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, but nothing happen in my page,, and i need not set image as background.

Comment: Yup, once that works you can set it as header. Try playing around with a little. I have used it on my website and it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery `animate()` can help here. The following code will move the image to a final left offset of 500px in 3s on page load. Be sure to specify the inital position in the CSS.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.move').animate({left:'500px'},3000);
});
```

Note: jQuery is not the best javascript library to use when animating things. Try GSAP instead. greensock.com/gsap

Comment: can you make jsfiddle for me?

Comment: thanks.. still i didn't get, once moved and stopped. but i need moving continously and slowly andsmoothly like marquee.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done using jQuery:

```
    function moveRight() {
    $("#b").css('left', '0px');
    $("#b").animate({
        left: "+=300"
    }, 5000, moveRight)
}

$(document).ready(function () {

    moveRight();

});
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/iyogesh/gLr8vqbv/

Comment: thanks, but i m not asking like this, moving continously and slowly andsmoothly..

Comment: @selva you can set duration as per your need. then it will move slowly.

Comment: @selva download and include framework file (css, js etc.) in html and play with that

Answer (score 0):

Try below if you want to use pure javascript and does not want to have a heavy library dependency such as query. Here is [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ue2378c0/)

```
var $el = document.querySelector('.move');
var left = 0;
var id = requestAnimationFrame(frame);

function frame() {
    left++;
    $el.style.left = left + 'px';
    if (left == 250) {
        cancelAnimationFrame(id);
    } else {
        requestAnimationFrame(frame);
    }
}
```